# Axios, Proxy request seems like not working

Tags: javascript, axios

It seems like the `axios` library doesn't work as it should and I don't know what's wrong.

First, to explain. I am new to `axios` and the company I work has setup the API server using `nGinx` with `proxy pass`.

So let say, the API Server is under the domain: `https://www.api.com` and the `api` endpoints are located under `https://www.api.com/api/`.

Then, we are going to create a SSR application, using the `axios` library to make the request to this server, but the point is to use the `proxy settings` of the `axios`, in a way that the finally requests will not be like that: `https://www.api.com/api/endpoint` but like that: `https://www.js-app.com/api/endpoint`.

So, currently I have the following class:

```
class WebApiService {
    constructor() {
        this.deferred = Q.defer();
        this.$http = axios.create();
    }

    async call(config) {
        WebApiService._setDefaultApiCallHeader(config);

        try {
            const result = await this.$http(config);
            this.deferred.resolve(result);
        } catch( error ) {
            this.deferred.reject(error);
        }

        return this.deferred.promise;
    }

    static _setDefaultApiCallHeader(config) {
        config.headers = config.headers || {};

        if (window.sessionStorage['Authorization'] !== 'undefined') {
            config.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${window.sessionStorage['Authorization']}`;
        }


        // HERE I SETUP THE PROXY SETTINGS
        if ( /^\/api\//.test(config.url) ) {
            config.proxy = config.proxy || {};
            config.proxy.host = 'https://www.api.com';
        }
    }
}
```

So now, when I utilize this class from another place in my app using code like this:

```
const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  url: '/api/v0/configs',
  data: { domain: window.location.hostname }
};

const websiteConfig = await this.webApiService.call(options);
```

In my browser console I get a 404 error and that's because the `axios` still request the API call from my localhost instead from the remote server.

The error I get is like that:

[image]

Also the `axios` settings inside the request Interceptor are like that:

[image]

So, you think I do something in wrong? You think I try to achieve something that's not possible? Is there any solution to this situation? Any idea on how to approach this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are misusing axios proxy option. This option as far as I understand is intended to put there some actual proxy. And you don't need all this in your case.

You should serve your app-client from your server https://www.js-app.com, below is an example of Nginx config:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
 }
```

And for the API Server:

```
location /api {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:8081; # here you put your backend server port
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  proxy_read_timeout 600s;
}
```

Examples are from this [nice article](https://www.moveoapps.com/blog/set-node-js-application-production-nginx-reverse-proxy/) that may help.

Or you may google some others, with title similar to "How to Set Up a Node.js Application for Production with Nginx Reverse Proxy"

If you can not put your backend server like that, you can always do something behind Nginx or in Nginx config to actually send request to api.com/api

Comment: I am going to check this with my co-workers and then I'll be back with comments. Thank you very much for your response :)